# How to set logic in property using Fody

Tags: mvvm, fody-propertychanged

If  I need to set some data in my property by call some method like :

```
private List<string> _country = GetCountries();
public List<string> Country 
{
    get
    {
          return _country ;
    }
    set
    {
          _country = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Country");
    }
}
```

Now If we use Fody, then above private variable will remove and will be like below by using [ImplementPropertyChanged].

```
public List<string> Country  {get;Set;}
```

In above how GetCountries() can call to set data into property ?

Comment: I am thinking about this :
  public List<string> Country  {get;Set;}  = GetCountries();
But do not know it works or not ?

Comment: That's the exact equivalent of the first, so why wouldn't it work?